# Patching to TFS API with JSON gives 400 error (Bad Request)

Tags: c#, .net, rest, api, tfs

I'm trying to do a patch http request to change one of the fields in TFS through the TFS REST API. I've tried several approaches, but I always end up with 400 error. Here is what I have right now:

```
        public void SetFieldValue(string value, string path, int id)
    {
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(PatchwebAPIUrl("wit/workitems", id.ToString()));
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json-patch+json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "PATCH";
        httpWebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic" + Base64authorizationToken();
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "[{\"op\":\"replace\"," +
                          $"\"path\":\"{path}\"," +
                          $"\"value\":\"{value}\"}}]";


            streamWriter.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json));
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

    }
```

---

And the test method that calls this method:

```
        [TestMethod()]
    public void setFieldValue()
    {
        TFSWebAPIImplementation webAPI = new TFSWebAPIImplementation();
        webAPI.SetFieldValue("654321", "/fields/Custom.Tracking", 61949);
    }
```

The PatchwebAPIUrl("...") Method is fine, and returns a good URL, when I navigate to it I get the JSON data that I want to edit. I'm not 100% on the path variable but it's used the same as the example provided from Microsoft. The authorization works, just based on the fact that when I mess with it I get a 401 instead.

Comment: Are you missing a space character after "Basic" in the header?

Comment: I just tried it, I still get a 400 error.

Comment: bad request most of the time means you are sending something that is wrong to the server, not authentication. For sure you should have a space after "Basic". Have you tried to search the documentation to see if there is not something maybe missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys, so unfortunately none of your solutions worked, and I think it's because there was always an extra set of curly brackets on the outside that the TFS API didn't like. Here is my solution that solved my problem:

```
public void SetFieldValue(string value, string path, int id)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Base64authorizationToken());
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
            using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
            {
                writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                writer.WriteStartArray(); // [

                writer.WriteStartObject(); // {
                writer.WritePropertyName("op"); // "Product:"
                writer.WriteValue("replace");
                writer.WritePropertyName("path");
                writer.WriteValue(path);
                writer.WritePropertyName("value");
                writer.WriteValue(value);
                writer.WriteEndObject(); //}
                writer.WriteEnd(); // ]

            }

            var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, PatchwebAPIUrl("wit/workitems", id.ToString())) { Content =  new StringContent(sb.ToString().Trim(new char[] {'{','}'}), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json") };
            var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;


            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my sample code:

Class for work item:

```
public class WorkItemAtrr
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int id;
    [JsonProperty("rev")]
    public int rev;
    [JsonProperty("fields")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> fields;
    [JsonProperty("_links")]
    public Dictionary<string, Link> _links;
    [JsonProperty("relations")]
    public List<Relation> relations;
    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public string url;
}

public class Link
{
    [JsonProperty("href")]
    public string href;
}

public class Relation
{
    [JsonProperty("rel")]
    public string rel;
    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public string url;
    [JsonProperty("attributes")]
    public RelationAttribute attributes;
}

public class RelationAttribute
{
   [JsonProperty("comment")]
   public string comment = "";
   [JsonProperty("isLocked")]
   public bool isLocked;
}
```

Class for new and updated fields:

```
public class NewField
{
    [JsonProperty("op")]
    public string op = "add";
    [JsonProperty("path")]
    public string path;
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public object value;
}
```

Class for exceptions:

```
public class RestApiExceptionContainer
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int id;
    [JsonProperty("innerException")]
    public string innerException;
    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string message;
    [JsonProperty("typeName")]
    public string typeName;
    [JsonProperty("typeKey")]
    public string typeKey;
    [JsonProperty("errorCode")]
    public int errorCode;
    [JsonProperty("evenId")]
    public int eventId;
}
```

Method for update a work item:

```
private static WorkItemAtrr UpdateWorkItemRest()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> _fields = new Dictionary<string, string>();  

    _fields.Add("REFERENCE_NAME", "VALUE");

    var _updatedWi = UpdateWorkItem("ID", _fields).Result;
}
```

Method for preparing request:

```
public async Task<WorkItemAtrr> UpdatedWorkItem(int pId, Dictionary<String, String> pFields)
{
    //PATCH https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version={version}
    string _query_url = String.Format("https://YOUR_SERVER/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=1.0", pId);

    List<Object> flds = new List<Object>();

    foreach (var _key in pFields.Keys)
        flds.Add(new NewField { op = "add", path = "/fields/" + _key, value = pFields[_key] });

    HttpResponseMessage _response = await DoRequest(_query_url, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(flds), ClientMethod.PATCH);

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WorkItemAtrr>(await ProcessResponse(_response));
}
```

Universal method for request:

```
private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DoRequest(string pRequest, string pBody, ClientMethod pClientMethod)
{
    try
    {
        HttpClientHandler _httpclienthndlr = new HttpClientHandler();                

//update for your auth                 
        if (UseDefaultCredentials) _httpclienthndlr.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        else if (TFSDomain == "") _httpclienthndlr.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(TFSUserName, TFSPassword);
        else _httpclienthndlr.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(TFSUserName, TFSPassword, TFSDomain);


        using (HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient(_httpclienthndlr))
        {
            switch (pClientMethod)
            {
                case ClientMethod.GET:
                    return await _httpClient.GetAsync(pRequest);

                case ClientMethod.POST:
                    return await _httpClient.PostAsync(pRequest, new StringContent(pBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

                case ClientMethod.PATCH:
                    var _request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), pRequest);
                    _request.Content = new StringContent(pBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json");                            
                    return await _httpClient.SendAsync(_request);

                default:
                    return null;
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception _ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Http Request Error", _ex);
    }
}
```

Universal method for response:

```
public async Task<string> ProcessResponse(HttpResponseMessage pResponse)
{
    string _responseStr = "";

    if (pResponse != null)
    {
        if (pResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            _responseStr = await pResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        else
        {
            _responseStr = await pResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var _error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RestApiExceptionContainer>(_responseStr);

            throw new RestApiException(_error);
        }
    }

    return _responseStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A 400 means that the request was malformed. In other words, the data stream sent by the client to the server didn't follow the rules.

In the case of a REST API with a JSON payload, 400's are typically, used to indicate that the JSON is invalid in some way according to the API specification for the service.

So, the issue is caused by the JSON body.

Just try it like below:

```
string json = "[{\"op\":\"replace\",\"path\":\"/fields/System.Title\",\"value\":\"Title\"}]";
```

---

You can also use below sample to update the fields with PATCH method via the REST API, it works for me:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace UpdateWorkItemFiled0411
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string password = "xxxx";
            string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "username", password )));

            Object[] patchDocument = new Object[1];

            patchDocument[0] = new { op = "replace", path = "/relations/attributes/comment", value = "Adding traceability to dependencies" };


            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentials);


                var patchValue = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patchDocument), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json");

                var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/21?api-version=1.0") { Content = patchValue };
                var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;


                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @GeorgeCena What about the sample code? is that working for you? or same results in a 400 error?

Answer (score 0):

Also you may use nugate package [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/).

Connect to team project from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/get-started/rest/samples?view=vsts):

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;

...

//create uri and VssBasicCredential variables
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
VssBasicCredential credentials = new VssBasicCredential("", personalAccessToken);

using (ProjectHttpClient projectHttpClient = new ProjectHttpClient(uri, credentials))
{
    IEnumerable<TeamProjectReference> projects = projectHttpClient.GetProjects().Result;                    
}
```

my code to add comments:

```
JsonPatchDocument PatchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument(); 

PatchDocument.Add( 
    new JsonPatchOperation() 
    { 
        Operation = Operation.Add, 
        Path = "/fields/System.History", 
        Value = "Changes from script" 
    } 
); 

VssCredentials Cred = new VssCredentials(true); 
WorkItemTrackingHttpClient WIClient = new WorkItemTrackingHttpClient(new Uri("http://YOUR_SERVER/tfs/DefaultCollection"), Cred); 
WorkItem result = WIClient.UpdateWorkItemAsync(PatchDocument, id).Result;
```

Comment: I've been trying this and i can't get the packages to work no matter what.